# How can I specify Selenoid server for Cypress runs?

Tags: javascript, cypress, remote-access, selenoid

I'm trying to utilize an existing Selenoid farm to run Cypress tests, found no relevant docs so far.
Is there any easy way to specify remote browser/browser farm URL in Cypress tests/configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenoid only supports Selenium tests. Cypress is completely independent technology not compatible with Selenium. However remote Cypress tests execution is supported in another related product called Moon. https://aerokube.com/moon/latest/#cypress